# When multi MessageConsumer connect to same queue(Websphere MQ),how to load balance message-consumer?

Tags: jms, websphere, load-balancing, ibm-mq

I am Using WebSphere MQ 7,and I have two clients connected to the same QMgr and consuming messages from same queue, like following code:

```
 while (true) {
        TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
        if (message != null) {
            System.out.println("*********************" + message.getText());
        }
    }
```

I found only one client always retrieve messages. Is there any method to let consume-message load balancing in two client?  Any config options in MQ Server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When managing queue handles, it is MUCH faster for WMQ to put them in a stack rather than a LIFO queue.  So if the messages arrive on the queue slower than it takes to process them, it is possible that an instance will process the message and perform another GET, which WMQ pushes down on the stack.  The result is that only one instance will see messages in a low-volume use case.

In larger environments where there are many instances waiting on messages, it is possible that activity will round-robin amongst a portion of those instances while the other instances starve for messages.  For example, with 10 GETters on the queue you may see three processing messages and 7 idle.

Although this is considerably faster for MQ, it is confusing to customers who are not aware of how it works internally and so they open PMRs asking this exact question.  IBM had to choose among several alternatives:

- Adding several code paths to manage by stack for performance when fully loaded, versus manage by LIFO for apparent balancing when lightly loaded.  This bloats the code, adds many new decision points to introduce errors and solves a problem that was one of perception rather than reliability or performance.
- Educate the customers as to how it works. Of course, once you document it, then you can't change it.  The way I found out about this was attending the "WMQ Internals" presentation at IMPACT. It's not in the Infocenter so IBM can change it, but it is available for customers.
- Do nothing. Although this is the best result from the code design point of view, the behavior is counter-intuitive.  Users need to understand why things do not behave as expected and will waste time trying to find the configuration that results in the desired behavior, or open a PMR.

I don't know for sure that it still works this way but I expect that it does.  The way I used to test it was to put many messages on the queue at once and then see how they were distributed.  If you drop about 50 messages on the queue in one unit of work, you should see a better distribution between the two instances.

How do you drop 50 messages on the queue at once?  First generate them with the applications turned off or to a spare queue.  If you generated them in the target queue,  use the [Q program](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01) to move them to the spare queue.  Now start the apps and make sure the queue's `IPPROC` count equals however many instances of the app you started.  Using Q again, copy all of the messages to the original queue in a single unit of work.  Since they all become available on the queue at once, your two app instances should both immediately be passed a message.  If you used copy instead of move, you can repeat this as often as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is not doing much,  so one instance can probably handle the full load. Try implementing a more realistic workload, or,  simpler yet,  put a Thread.sleep in the client.