# Two consumers on same Websphere MQ JMS Queue, both receiving same message

Tags: jms, load-balancing, messaging, ibm-mq, mq

I am working with someone who is trying to achieve a load-balancing behavior using JMS Queues with IBM Websphere MQ.  As such, they have multiple Camel JMS consumers configured to read from the same Queue.  Despite that this behavior is undefined according to the JMS spec (last time I looked anyway), they expect a sort of round-robin / load-balancing behavior.  And, while the spec leaves this undefined, I'm led to believe  that the normal behavior of Websphere MQ is to deliver the message to only one of the consumers, and that it *may* do some type of load-balancing.  See here, for example: [When multi MessageConsumer connect to same queue(Websphere MQ),how to load balance message-consumer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800829/when-multi-messageconsumer-connect-to-same-queuewebsphere-mq-how-to-load-balan)

But in this particular case, it appears that *both* consumers are receiving the same message.

Can anyone who is more of an expert with Websphere MQ shed any light on this?  Is there any situation where this behavior is expected? Is there any configuration change that can alleviate this?

I'm leaning towards telling everyone here to use the native Websphere MQ clustering facility and go away from having multiple consumers pointing at the same Queue, but that will be a big change for them, so I'd love to discover a way to make this work.

Not that I'm a fan of relying on anything that's undefined, but if they're willing to rely on IBM specific behavior, I'll leave that up to them.

Answer (score 3):

The only way for them to both receive the same messages are:

1. There are multiple copies of the message.
2. The apps are browsing the message without a lock, then circling back to delete it.
3. The apps are backing out a transaction and making the message available again.
4. The connection is severed before the app acknowledges the message.

Having multiple apps compete for messages in a queue is a recommended practice.  If one app goes down the queue is still served.  In a cluster this is crucial because the cluster will continue to direct messages to the un-served queue instance until it fills up.

If it's a Dev system, install [SupportPac MA0W](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W) and tell it to trace just that one queue and you will be able to see exactly what is happening.

See the JMS spec in section 4.4.  The provider must never deliver a second copy of an acknowledged message.  Exception is made for session handling in 4.4.13 which I cover in #4 above.  That's pretty unambiguous and part of the official spec so not an IBM-specific behavior.

Comment: Thanks T.Rob.  I haven't looked at the actual spec in years, but I had thought that when there were multiple consumers on a Queue (as opposed to a Topic) that the behavior was completely undefined.   But maybe the "never deliver a second copy of an acknowledged message" provision trumps that.

Comment: It's the delivery order among competing consumers that is undefined.  The delivery of the messages is also impacted by the QOS settings.  If the app specifies lazy acknowledgement then it might get dupes.  But if the message is queued and acked and not rolled back or otherwise has an exception, you get once-and-only-once delivery.